# sweetalert1 JS plugin migration to Sweealert2

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I need to migrate my sweetalert1 JS plugin to Sweetalert2 Plugin.

However I am at a complete loss on how to migrate the following code:

```
swal("A wild Pikachu appeared! What do you want to do?", {
  buttons: {
    cancel: "Run away!",
    catch: {
      text: "Throw Pokéball!",
      value: "catch",
    },
    defeat: true,
  },
})
.then((value) => {
  switch (value) {

    case "defeat":
      swal("Pikachu fainted! You gained 500 XP!");
      break;

    case "catch":
      swal("Gotcha!", "Pikachu was caught!", "success");
      break;

    default:
      swal("Got away safely!");
  }
});
```

sweetalert1: https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/#advanced-examples

sweetalert2: https://sweetalert2.github.io/

Any help in formatting the code to sweetalert2 please?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, SweetAlert2 doesn't allow more than 2 buttons by default, but you can accomplish the same by using custom HTML buttons with jQuery bindings [as described in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39268318/more-than-2-buttons-on-sweetalert-2). For your specific problem, the outcome should be more or less like this:

```js
    $(document).on('click', '.SwalBtn1', function() {
        //Some code 1
        console.log('Button 1');
        swal.clickConfirm();
        swal("Got away safely!");
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.SwalBtn2', function() {
        //Some code 2 
        console.log('Button 2');
        swal.clickConfirm();
        swal("Gotcha!", "Pikachu was caught!", "success");
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.SwalBtn3', function() {
        // Some code 3
        console.log('Button 3');
        swal.clickConfirm();
        swal("Pikachu fainted! You gained 500 XP!");
    });

    swal({
        title: 'Oh oh!',
        html: "<p>A wild Pikachu appeared! What do you want to do?</p>" +
            '<button class="SwalBtn1 swal2-custom-button swal2-styled">' + 'Run Away!' + '</button>' +
            '<button class="SwalBtn2 swal2-custom-button swal2-styled">' + 'Throw Pokéball!' + '</button>' +
            '<button class="SwalBtn3 swal2-custom-button swal2-styled">' + 'Defeat!' + '</button>',
        showCancelButton: false,
        showConfirmButton: false
    });
```

```css
.swal2-custom-button {
  background-color: #3085d6;
  color: #fff;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: .2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@7.25.0/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

There is a [documentation page](https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2/wiki/Migration-from-SweetAlert-to-SweetAlert2) on the SweetAlert2 repo that gives a better explanation (and cool examples!) on migrating the rest of the component. But this should get you in the path of what you need to do.