# Sweetalert 2 more than 2 buttons. Don't close on deny

Tags: sweetalert2

I'm using the example in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63925651/10136374) answer to display more than just 2 buttons on a swal.
When the user clicks the deny button, I want to change something in the html of the swal without closing it. Right now, the swal is closed when the deny button is clicked.
Where and how do I specify that the swal shouldn't close?

Answer (score 0):

I just added the `preDeny` parameter which allows to keep a modal opened by returning
`false`:

```js
Swal.fire({
  title: 'The "deny" button will not close me',
  showDenyButton: true,
  preDeny: () => {
    return false
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@10"></script>
```

Read more about `preDeny`: https://sweetalert2.github.io/#pre-deny